# Trying to find an online chapter story about being that observes and influences the evolution of an alien species/society

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a story from a website with many chapter stories written by different authors (I don't remember the website name unfortunately, but I think that it had a dark color scheme and many different authors' stories on it, comments below each of the chapters, and not an online magazine/publication). It's not a novel as far as I know; it's the style where the author would upload a new short chapter every couple weeks or so.

I was reading it during the fall of 2016, and I think new chapters were still being posted during that time. There were already a lot (over 30) of chapters by then, and I think the author was nearing the end of the story.

In the beginning, a being comes into existence, kind of like a god but with very limited energy and powers. Over the course of the story, this species begins to evolve (early on I think they are rather lizard-like) and this being/protagonist is able to occasionally influence their evolution (although this drains a lot of its energy). Their society becomes increasingly advanced (tools, fore, etc) and the being observes their development from afar.

There are a couple members of the species that the protagonist/being feels close to (although the protagonist can't talk to any living creatures on the planet) and follows throughout their lives. One might be named Star or Shimmer or something like that? It's a very sad moment when one of them dies since the being really cares about them.

Comment: Hello and welcome, your question has had a reasonably good start but we could always use some more details. Little things such as when you may have read it and when you think it may have been posted would help. Any name for the website even if you're unsure would also help guide us on our way. If you haven't already, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can add in any more details.

Comment: Thanks! I just added some more details!